# SWIFT: UIView which moves up with keyboard, moves very strangely after initial move, doesn't come back down

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, constraints

So I have a UIView which I want to move up and down as the textfield within it is editing and dismissing (keyboard appears and hides).  Here is my keyboard observers, and the UIView's default constraint, all inside the viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    
    let radiusViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchRadiusView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: super.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -30.0)
```

Here are the keyboard functions:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     print("keyboardWillShow")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.searchRadiusView.center.y += (-1 * keyboardSize.height)
        
        view.constraints[18].constant += (-1 * keyboardSize.height)
        
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

     })
    }
}

   @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
     print("keyboardWillHide")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.searchRadiusView.center.y += 1 * keyboardSize.height
        
        view.constraints[18].constant -= (-1 * keyboardSize.height)

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

     })
    }

}
```

constraints[18] is the constraint I created in my viewDidLoad.  When I first tap the textfield, the UIView moves up the correct amount.  Then, when I type my first character, it moves up that same amount again, and is now near the top of the screen.  When I dismiss it, it moves back down to the height it was just previously at (just above the height of the keyboard, which is now dismissed).  The next time I edit text, it moves up again, but not the full keyboard.height amount for some  reason.  When I dismiss, it goes down the FULL keyboard height.  This then repeats until the UIView falls off the bottom of the screen.  This movement is so strange and I have no idea what the problem is.  All I wanted is for it to move up and down with the keyboard.  Any ideas how to fix this? thanks

Comment: How to move the interface when a text field is about to be obscured by the virtual keyboard is a well-solved problem with established solutions. I would suggest using one of those.

Comment: thats what I am trying to do, I've been researching solutions and this implementation is one of them.  I'm trying to get it to work for my project, which as you can see, is giving me trouble

Comment: Well clearly it isn't a very good solution. :)

Comment: do you have any insight on why my solution is so wonky? As I read it, it doesn't seem all that bad, yet it doesn't work.  I asked a question about how to do this stuff before, and in his answer someone told me the way I was doing it was wrong, so he linked me some  solutions.  my code is built off one of those.  I've looked through a ton of them, and I just can't quite get it to work for me

Comment: It was probably me. :) Naturally I like my own solution best: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/xcode12/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift

Comment: @matt hey dude, I've been messing with stuff, and I just tested my original code again.  It works perfectly when simulated on my iPhone 8.   Works better, but not perfect, on the iPhone 8 xcode simulator,  then on iPhone 11, has the problem I described above.   Any idea why? This is so weird. I really can't find a reason why my code wouldn't work the way I want, and the fact that it works perfectly on my phone is making me question what the heck is going on.  why would it work differently on iPhone 8 simulator than an actual iPhone 8? Do you have any thought? Could the issue be other than code

Comment: What version of Xcode on what kind of computer?

Comment: Xcode 11.7 on 2015 Macbook Air

Comment: Boy, you'd think a 2015 Macbook Air would be able handle this. Have you got a demo project demonstrating the issue? I could try it on my machine (which is a lot older than that).

Comment: i know right? How can I make a demo project for you? Or do you want me to screen record or something

Comment: Would need to be actual project. Could post on github for example.

Comment: I already have it on GitHub, its private tho can you still clone it like that?  If so I can just link it

Comment: I don't want to see the whole thing, just enough to demonstrate the one issue.

Comment: yea ok, so how can I give you the little snippet of code? Do you just need where these functions are and the viewDidLoad setup stuff? Sorry, Im new to sharing code

Comment: I'd like to see an actual working project that is just enough so I can run the app on my simulator and see what it does.

Comment: ah, ok, I will try to make it real quick, then send the github link

Comment: Here's the link.  Made it as similar to my actual project as possible.  Weirdly, the View in this simulator is similar in that it tends to move up less distance every successive time, then move down correctly everytime.  Only difference is, in my real simulator, when I first edit the textfield, it moves up, then when I type one character, it moves up again the same amount, and looks double the height it should be.  In this new simulator, it doesn't do that.  Heres the project: https://github.com/derekvandermark/DemoSlideUpTextField

Comment: Your entire way of accessing and speaking of constraints is wrong. Plus, In your `viewDidLoad` you add a bottom constraint to the blue view (`radiusViewConstraint`). But you already _have_ a bottom constraint to the blue view, so if you now change one of them, you have a conflict (which in fact is noted in the console when you click in the text field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing too many things wrong for me to list, so I have just fixed your project and made a pull request. Merge the pull request into your repo and you will see that it now works fine.

Just for the record, here are some of the main things you were doing wrong:

- You added a bottom constraint, in code, to the blue view. But you already *had* a bottom constraint on the blue view. Thus you now have two of them, and any change in one of them will cause a conflict. The Xcode console was telling you very clearly that this was happening, but you ignored what it told you.
- You were changing the constraint constant but also changing the blue view `center`. That probably caused no harm but it was pointless. You cannot govern a view's position by its `center` if you are governing it with constraints; they are opposites.
- In your show and hide methods you examined `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`. That's wrong. You want to examine `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. The question is not where the keyboard is *now* but where it *will be* when it finishes moving.
- The animation is wrong. There is no need for a UIView animation; you are already in an animation block. Just call `layoutIfNeeded` and the animation will happen together with the movement of the keyboard.
- Your entire way of speaking of and accessing constraints is wrong. You use an incorrect expression `super.view` (you probably meant `self.view`). But even more important, you attempt to access the desired constraint by saying `self.constraints[2]`. That sort of thing is fragile in the extreme. The correct approach is to keep a reference to the actual constraint (an instance property). In this situation, since the constraint already exists (in the storyboard), that reference can be an outlet.

So, with all that said, here's my rewrite of your code; this is the *complete* code needed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var originalConstant: CGFloat = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        self.originalConstant = bottomConstraint.constant
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        sampleTextField.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboardWillShow")
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant += keyboardSize.height + 5
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        print("keyboardWillHide")
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.originalConstant
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

With all of that said, the code is *still* wrong, because you are not taking account of the very real possibility that you will get a `keyboardWillShow` notification *when the keyboard is already showing*. However, I leave that for your later investigation.

Comment: Well, thanks so much for the time and effort.  I appreciate the help.  As you can see, I am very new to constraints and views haha.  I was aware that I was setting a constraint in the storyboard and in code, although I didn't know I could make a constraint outlet, that makes much more sense.  I suppose I should've realized that was a problem.  As for your last statement, 'keyboardWillShow' gets called once at the beggining everytime, and once when you type the first character for the first time.  If it calls at other points that that, I'll figure it out.  Again, thanks a ton

Comment: One way we can do this is by not using `+=`. Instead, just set `self.bottomConstraint.constant` to an actual number. That way, it is just right all the time.

Comment: Ah yes, that also makes much more sense.  I modeled this after some other code I found on stack overflow, but I should've realized to change that.. Again, Thanks!

Comment: Still, I think the code I pointed to in my link is a much better approach. We slide the _whole_ interface, the right amount, at the right time.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'the whole interface'? Is it bad to only move what needs to be moved?

Comment: Is there a way to run just that example in xcode or I have to clone the entire book?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/xcode12/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift

Comment: Dont wanna bug you anymore but you're experienced so I wanna pick ur brain.  I noticed you put 'self.' in front of lots of constants and variables and whatnot even though you don't HAVE to.  Is that just considered good coding practice?  I'm assuming its slightly safer at avoiding using the wrong constant?

Comment: That's a religious war and I'm not going to get into it.